# Why it's getting an error while * as an argument

Tags: java

```
class Simcal1{
    public static void main(String []args){

        int a = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        int b = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
        char ch = args[1].charAt(0);

        switch(ch){
            case '+':System.out.println("Addition :" + (a+b) );   
                 break;
            case '-':System.out.println("Subtraction :" + (a-b) );
                 break;
            case '/':System.out.println("Division :"+ (a/b) );   
                 break;
            case '*':System.out.println("Multification :"+ (a*b) );
                 break;
            default:System.out.println("Enter valid choice");
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

why i am getting an error while i give 5 * 5 as argument?, but in other case as 4 + 5 it's work fine.

Comment: If you're getting an error, please include the exact text of the error in your question.  If the error references a line number in your code, please indicate in your included code where that line number is.

Comment: Because `*` is a special character in the command line.

Comment: You shell is probably expanding * to every filename in the current directory. Try putting the star in single quotes.

Comment: It's probably better to expect one argument which is the full expression. Then you don't have to worry about escaping anything. "1 + 2" would work the same as "3 * 4". You would look at the characters of `args[0]` rather than `args[0,1 and 2]`

Comment: By the way, it's spelled 'Multi**pl**ication'